# facebookredirect.axd results 191 error

Tags: facebook, webresource.axd

my facebook page is redirecting to a facebookredirect.axd that results a 191 error.  I cleaned up my web config can someone please tell me how to fix this error. there was also a fix on IIS7 that i can't figure out. Anyone has a solution please let me know thank you.

i already have this on web.config

```
<configSections>
    <section type="Facebook.FacebookConfigurationSection, Facebook" name="facebookSettings" allowLocation="true" allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
  </configSections>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="Secret" value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"/>
    <add key="AppID" value="aaaaaaaaaaaaaa"/>
    <add key="APIKey" value="aaaaaaaaaaaaaa"/>
    <add key="Callback" value="http://www.domain.ca/rest/Default.aspx"/>
  </appSettings>
  <facebookSettings 
    appId="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" 
    appSecret="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" 
    canvasPage="http://apps.facebook.com/rest" 
    canvasUrl="http://www.domain.ca/rest/Default.aspx" 
    secureCanvasUrl = "https://www.domain.ca/rest/Default.aspx"
    cancelUrlPath=""/>
  <system.web>

    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="*" path="facebookredirect.axd" type="Facebook.Web.FacebookAppRedirectHttpHandler, Facebook.Web"/>
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <handlers>
      <add name="facebookredirect" path="facebookredirect.axd" verb="*" type="Facebook.Web.FacebookAppRedirectHttpHandler, Facebook.Web"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

facebook setting
canvas url = http://www.domain.ca/rest/default.aspx?
securecanvas url = http://www.domain.ca/rest/default.aspx?

please help to fix this error.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the ? marks from the URLs in your settings.

Comment: i did that and i still get this 191 errror